# How to update a single column in single row in a datatable using LinQ

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I'm working on a project that uses a Master database (a datatable) to drive downloading of files from an FTP server.  During the process, I create a local database (another datatable) for each client in the master database.  Here is the code that I use to create a client database:

```
Console.WriteLine(" Building Client Database")
Clientdatabase = New DataTable
Clientdatabase = DataBaseTable.Clone
Dim RowList = (From row In DataBaseTable.AsEnumerable() Where (row.Field(Of String)("co") = CompanyID))
For Each RowItem In RowList
    Clientdatabase.ImportRow(RowItem)
Next
```

This code is working as expected; the Clientdatabase is accurate in what it contains.  My problem is updating a field in the Clientdatabase.  From within a loop, I'm getting each record that contains the full path and file name of the target file on the FTP server, then I attempt to update the clientdatabase with the local path and I can't get it to work.  From within the loop this code is performing the logic and downloading the file:

```
Dim FileList = (From row In DataBaseTable.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(x) New With {
     Key .co = x.Field(Of String)("co"),
     Key .path = x.Field(Of String)("path"),
     Key .OriginalFileName = x.Field(Of String)("OriginalFileName"),
     Key .DocumentID = x.Field(Of String)("DocumentID")
               }).Where(Function(s) s.co = CompanyID).ToList)
Console.Write(" Downloading Files : ")
Dim CursorArray() As String = Split("\,|,/,-", ",")
Dim FileCounter As Integer = 1
For Each CompanyFile In FileList
    Dim ThisFile As String = CompanyFile.path.Replace("\", "/")
    Dim Results As TransferOperationResult = DownloadFromPath(ThisFile, DestinPath)
    Dim TmpParts() As String = Split(ThisFile, "/")
    Dim LocalName As String = TmpParts(UBound(TmpParts))
    If Results.IsSuccess Then
        UpdateCDBPath(CompanyID, CompanyFile.DocumentID, LocalName)
        ReportData &= CompanyID & ",Success," & CompanyFile.OriginalFileName & "," & ThisFile & vbCrLf
    Else
        ReportData &= CompanyID & ",Failed," & CompanyFile.OriginalFileName & "," & ThisFile & vbCrLf
    End If
    FileCounter += 1
    Console.Write(CursorArray(FileCounter Mod 4) & Chr(8))
Next
```

The call to update (UpdateCDBPath) contains the following code:

```
Sub UpdateCDBPath(ByVal CompanyID As String, ByVal DocumentID As String, TargetValue As String)
    Dim result = (From row In Clientdatabase.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(x) New With {
                    Key .DocumentID = x.Field(Of String)("DocumentID"),
                    Key .Co = x.Field(Of String)("co")
                }).Where(Function(s) s.DocumentID = DocumentID And s.Co = CompanyID ) Select Clientdatabase)
    For Each ItemRow In result
        ItemRow.Rows(0).Item("Path") = TargetValue
    Next
End Sub
```

The problem is within this code block.  DocumentID is a GUID that is unique within the client that uniquely identifies the document, TargetValue is the replacement path (local path to the file).  If I'm understanding the Linq correctly (and I'm not), it should only return the rows I'm interested in (1), thus how I'm setting the new path.  I've tried countless examples from various examples and can't make it work. When I check the Clientdatabase, none of the path fields are updated.  I've also confirmed that after saving the Clientdatabase locally, the fields are still the same.  Can some one please point me in the right direction, tell me where I went wrong or something so I can solve this.  I eventually will need to update other fields in the clientdatabase; this is the first one.  Thanks in advance for any and all help that might come my way!

Comment: It looks like `s.Co = DocumentID` should be `s.Co = CompanyID`

Comment: I have read that LINQ (Language Independent **Query**) is for querying data. Why would you want to force it to do a non-query?

Comment: @ Mary.  The Client datatable is huge, and each row will need to be updated individually.  So I was trying to use a where clause to update each row as the process move along.  I don't know the row number in advanced to use a more direct method and everything I've seen uses the dt.rows(#) syntax.  Cycling through each row would be very slow.  Is there another method that I could Use?

Comment: @ItsPete  Thanks for pointing that out.  I've edited the source code (and this post) and tested again (several times); the results variable returns the entire client data table and not just the one in question.

Comment: I've found that in huge tables, using the sqlquery might be much faster. With Linq you'd have to iterate over all the records. You can use a regular sql command to do it much faster. Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linq for `result` is returning a `EnumerableRowCollection(Of System.Data.DataTable)`, meaning that it contains a list of rows that are the entire `Clientdatabase`.

As each row contains the entire `DataRowCollection`, `ItemRow.Rows(0).Item("Path") = TargetValue` will update only the first row in `Clientdatabase` as many times as there are records in `results`.

Changing the query to return an `EnumerableRowCollection(Of System.Data.DataRow)` allows each row to be accessed directly in a loop:

```
Sub UpdateCDBPath(ByVal CompanyID As String, ByVal DocumentID As String, TargetValue As String)
    Dim result = From row In Clientdatabase.AsEnumerable()
                 Where row.Field(Of String)("DocumentID") = DocumentID AndAlso
                       row.Field(Of String)("co") = CompanyID
                 Select row

    For Each ItemRow In result
        ItemRow.Item("Path") = TargetValue
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: AWESOME!  Works like I would expect it, a Linq Update.  Just as a note: there is an extra ) as the end of the result def line.  Thank you very much.  With minor changes to the routine it permits the updating of any column in the result set.